# Solving coupled first order PDEs in three dimensions

Tags: partial-differential-equations, characteristics

Yesterday I asked [a question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4441004/solving-divergence-pde) asking how a system of 1st order PDEs is solved. They can be written as

$$u_x+v_y+w_z=c(u, v, w, x, y, z)$$
$$u_y=v_x, \quad v_z=w_y, \quad u_z=w_x$$

In the particular case I'm interested in, $c(u, v, w, x, y, z)$ is linear in $u, v,$ and $w$. In the previous question, someone suggested to solve the equations  using the method of characteristics, but all of the literature I can find, as well as other questions on this forum, always solve for a single unknown $u$ (cf., [Chapter 3 of Evans' book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0821849743), [A](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_characteristics), [B](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3079071/solving-a-pde-first-order-in-three-variables), [C](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2078957/method-of-characteristics-with-3-partials), and [D](https://web.stanford.edu/class/math220a/handouts/firstorder.pdf)).

Maybe I'm missing something obvious, but I don't see how to generalize the method to three unknowns $u, v, w$.

Comment: You can use the method of characteristics by following the solution I gave [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3666725/help-solving-shallow-water-equations-initial-value-problem/3667446#3667446), as well as solutions by others [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/799360/method-of-characteristics-for-a-system-of-pdes) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2999117/method-of-characteristics-for-system-of-linear-transport-equations), provided the PDE system is diagonalisable. Also, are you sure it isn't $u_{y} = v_{x}$? And the system is overdetermined as is.

Comment: Thank you, I'll look at the solution. You're right, I did indeed make a mistake in the second equation.